# Display "open with" dialog again in Android

Tags: android, intentfilter, open-with

I have an Android app with intent filter for "http". After install the user get "open with" dialog when he press a url in the browser.
My question is: If the user chose by mistake "open with x always" and he wants to change his selection to open the url with another app, how can he get the "choose app" dialog again ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the cache of the application.

For clearing cache you have take permission -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```

Call `deleteCahce()` to clear cahe

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
        return dir.delete();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Clear the cache before showing "Open With".